# How to backup and restore sources when upgrading to a newer version?

Tags: backup, software-sources, restore

If I copy/paste the /etc/apt dir or just sources.list for that matter to a newer version, I will still have sources named for the old version (saucy for axample) which is not right. For example:

deb http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy universe

has to be now like:

deb http://si.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe

Is there a "correct" way of importing/exporting sources or I have to write a script for renaming the words?

Answer (score 0):

You dont *export* or *import* sources, at least I don't understand what you mean.

Just create a copy of /etc/apt/sources.lst and then edit the original file, replacing all occurrences of saucy with trusty. Then do `apt-get update` and you have the new package list. If you fancy it, you can then do a `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Export/import, backup/restore, move to another ubuntu machine, to a newer version, however you like.. I was hoping there is a better way of doing this. Thanks anyway!